# How to express this sum concisely in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a simple `R` beginner's question:

How do I express the sum below most concisely in `R`?

```
sum_{i=1}^n a / (a+i)
```

I tried the following, but there must be a better way, without actually calling `for`:

```
r<-0
for(i in 1:n){ r <- r + (a / (a+i)) }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's as simple as:

```
sum(a/(a+1:n))
```

Answer (score 3):

You just do:

```
r <- sum(a/(a+1:n))
```